# Mathematica IntervalGraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, documentation, intervals, combinatorica

I wanted to visualize an Interval Graph.Documentation says there exists a function [`IntervalGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/IntervalGraph.html) in Global which used to be in package Combinatorica before Mathematica 10.0. However I don't see any function named "IntervalGraph" available in 11.1. When I try to Import Package Combinatorica I get an warning

> General::compat: Combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality
>   has been superseded by preloaded functionality. The package now being
>   loaded may conflict with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for
>   details.
>
> SetDelayed::write: Tag Element in a_List[Element]{index___} is Protected.

After importing Combinatorica package (with the warnings) when I try to use the function IntervalGraph I get a Text result

```
In[2]:= IntervalGraph[{{1,10},{4,18}}]
Out[2]= - Graph:< 1,2,Undirected > -
```

Is it a mathematica bug ? is the function `IntervalGraph` not-existent now ? is the documentation wrong ? or is there any other ways to visualize the graph ?

Comment: Do not use [tag:bugs] as a tag until your observations have been verified to be a bug.

Comment: Where exactly does the documentation say that there is a built-in function called `IntervalGraph`? I do not believe it says such a thing.  However, you can easily replicate that functionality using `RelationGraph`.

Comment: @Szabolcs `IntervalGraph` shows up in the documentation for versions 10.4.1 and 11.1.1 (Windows 7).

Comment: @JimBaldwin Yes, in the Combinatorica documentation. Not as a builtin.